# Root on Android Things userdebug builds

Tags: root, android-things

In my Android Things app, I need to use `su` from runtime. However, Android Things system is built as userdebug build, so I can only access it from adb. I tried to both replace su binaries with no luck. I tried to disable `ro.secure` by unpacking and repacking `boot.img`, however flashed system still returns `getprop ro.secure` `0`. How can I achieve root in my Android Things device?

Comment: Fair enough. I'll re-edit the tag.

Comment: out of interest, what do you need runtime root for?

Comment: @Blundell I need to access serial port by python application ran in shell via termux script

Comment: You can do serial communication over UART without root, if that helps https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/pio/uart.html. Or if the python app is not on another device, you could convert that to Java?

Comment: This question is based on a fundamental misunderstanding of the purpose of "su" in the Android world - it has *never* been supposed to be something that apps could use.   And as Blundell explained, it's unnecessary.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I run a shell script on Android Things device at boot with root permissions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45065766/how-can-i-run-a-shell-script-on-android-things-device-at-boot-with-root-permissi)

Answer (score 0):

I had these scripts working on a quite early preview version, maybe 0.1 or 0.2. https://github.com/fmatosqg/androidthings_ndk/tree/master/app/src/main/script

Although I had to run it manually, there should be a place where I can add this script so it runs every boot, just like linux's /etc/rc.d

I don't remember how I got the script to work, but the idea is that one script simply exists to launch the other running as superuser, similar to what you would expect with `sudo <insert command here>`